# Minimal sets of generators for groups

Tags: group-theory

Does any infinite group contain a minimal set of generators?

This is not true for semigroups. But for groups?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my english :-(

Comment: Presumably you mean "Does every infinite group contain a minimal set of generators?". The word "any" is often ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no". For example, consider the Prüfer $p$-group $\mathbf{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$. A subset $X$ of $\mathbf{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ generates if and only if it contains elements of arbitrarily large order. In particular, if $X$ is any generating set, then you can always remove a finite number of elements from $X$ and still have a generating set, so $\mathbf{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ has no minimal generating set.

Comment: The additive group of rational numbers is another example.