# If $X$ generates $\Bbb{Q}$ then $X\setminus\{x\}$ also generates $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $X$ is a generator subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ then for $x\in X$,
>   $X\setminus\{x\}$ also generates $\Bbb{Q}$.

Clearly if I can express $x$ as a combination of the remaining generators we are done. After struggling for an hour I took a different approach: tried to show that if $\langle X\setminus\{x\}\rangle\not=\Bbb{Q}$, $\langle X\setminus\{x\}\rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}$. That is, if $G\leq\Bbb{Q}$ and $\langle X\setminus\{x\}\rangle\subset G$, then $G=\Bbb{Q}$. For this purpose it is enough to show that $x\in G$. But I doubt that this is true. Any ideas?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487820/additive-group-of-rationals-has-no-minimal-generating-set.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It’s not just "see also", the answer by Camilo Aresemena in the link you gave answers precisely that question. Perhaps we should mark that as a duplicate

Comment: In fact the solution of Julian Rosen to 487820 works here.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy yes, you are right. I saw the answer and should have marked the question as duplicate.