# Minimal generating set for (R,+)

Tags: group-theory, real-numbers

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a group under the common addition of real numbers. Does there exist a subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left<A\right>=\mathbb{R}$ and for every $\alpha\in A$, $\left<A-\{\alpha\}\right>\ne \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such set exists. The same argument given [for the rationals here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487820/additive-group-of-rationals-has-no-minimal-generating-set) works.

Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\langle A\rangle=\mathbb{R}$. Let $a\in A$. I claim that $A\setminus\{a\}$ still generates $\mathbb{R}$ as an abelian group.

Let $B=\langle A\setminus\{a\}\rangle$. Then $\mathbb{R}/B$ is cyclic (possibly trivial) since it is generated by $a+B$. Therefore $\mathbb{R}/B\cong\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}/B\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $n\geq 1$. But the additive group of $\mathbb{R}$ is divisible, hence so is any quotient, but no nontrivial cyclic group is divisible. Therefore $\mathbb{R}/B$ must be trivial, i.e., $B=\mathbb{R}$, so $A\setminus\{a\}$ also generates $\mathbb{R}$.

By induction, if $A$ is a generating set for the additive group of reals, then $A\setminus F$, for any finite subset $F$, is also a generating set; there is no minimal generating set for $\mathbb{R}$.